# Insert panels on a JScrollPane in a dynamic way

Tags: java, swing

I am working on an application that has to show a list of elements belonging to text documents (Notes).
If from the SWING editor of NetBeans itself the elements are duplicated, everything works correctly. The problem comes when I do it from code by manually adding the elements with the function (add ()).
I need to make a scrollable list which is composed of panels that include their own elements.

```
package notas.forms;

public class MainWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame
{

    public MainWindow() {
        initComponents();
        this.setResizable(false);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204)));

        jLabel4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/grap.png"))); // NOI18N

        jLabel5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/add.png"))); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(149, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addGap(108, 108, 108))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(197, 197, 197)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 167, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jScrollPane1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jScrollPane1.setName("listaNotas"); // NOI18N

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        jPanel4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jPanel4.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204)));
        jPanel4.setEnabled(false);

        jLabel2.setText("TITULO DE LA PUTA NOTA TENSANTE Y ASQUEROSA");

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/trash.png"))); // NOI18N

        jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));
        jLabel3.setText("3/12/2017");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
        jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
        jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 43, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(95, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(1343, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jPanel2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 384, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainWindow().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: *"I am working on an application that has to show a list of elements belonging to text documents (Notes)."* Use a `JList` with (shrugs) `TextDocument` objects in it. Use a `ListCellRenderer` for the details (it can include components).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If from the SWING editor of NetBeans itself the elements are duplicated, everything works correctly. The problem comes when I do it from code by manually adding the elements with the function (add ()).

The problem is NetBeans generates layout code using the GroupLayout. GroupLayout is complicated and requires multiple constraints to be supplied when you add components to the panel.

So when you use the add(...) method you need to provide the same constraints that NetBeans does.

However, the simpler solution is to not use NetBeans to generate your GUI code. Instead you can take control of the layout management and make your code simpler and easier to maintain.

For example you can do something like:

```
Box children = Box.createVerticalBox();
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
wrapper.add(children, BorderLayout.Page_Start);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( wrapper );
frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER)'
```

Now whenever you want to add a new panel to the scroll pane you simply do:

```
children.add( a new child panel );
children.revalidate();
```

The above code replaces all the GroupLayout code generated by the IDE.

Another option might be to use a `GridBagLayout`. It allows you to add components to cells on the panel.

Take the time to learn how to use layout managers. Start by reading the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).